# Adding two’s complements of a negative HEXADECIMAL number

Tags: assembly, arm, armv7

I am currently taking a class in assembly, which is taught by a teacher who clearly has long ago forgotten what is simple or complex, and thus tends to fly right past simple examples into complex ones.

We're just gotten to the point of writing our first program, a hello world style beginning.

A) How do we declare a null-terminated string, in this case? What command can be used to do this?

B) She never covered a EXPORT command in class- how does it function?

C) When she says it must be named differently from the code area- is DATA area naming free? Or are there certain words we have to use?

Thank you whomever can help me with this- I feel like I'm drowning here in complexity with no good resources to help. That said, as a last question- are there any good online resources to self-teach ArmV7 assembly? Its clear she isn't going to teach this in class to a level I can understand (most of the class has dropped, but I cant afford to), and I'm falling way behind trying to teach myself from Arm Docs- so are there any good code-academy style assembly courses you'd recommend for someone trying to pass a class essentially without a professor?

Comment: Read the code she gave you carefully - many of the requirements in your bullet points are already written for you. Your question A is already answered in the `DATA` section. Your question B has information revealed in the code's comments. Question C they are already named differently. Get the posted code working first, and then try to modify it for the specific sum asked.

Answer (score 1):

A) null terminated string in this case is meant an ASCII encoded string. ASCII encoding does use 7bits (0-127 values) per glyph, but for convenience the whole byte (8bits, 0-255 value) is used. "null terminated" means the value 0 marks end of such string. So bytes `65, 0` form string "A" with zero byte after A.

From the example source: `a   DCB "86590", 0` - `DCB` will be probably something like "declare byte", `"86590"` is a way how your assembler can produce byte values from ASCII string in source (each character is one value, for example last one `'0'` equals `48` (see ASCII table)), and the terminating `0` is appended in classic way as number.

That line in example can be written as
`a   DCB 0x38, 0x36, 0x35, 0x39, 0x30, 0x00`
^ that will produce the same byte values, just the source is written in different way.

B) EXPORT will make some symbol "public" in the resulting object file, so the linker will see it and can connect different object files with those symbols. If you would remove `EXPORT main`, linking would fail with "main" undefined.

C) never seen this particular assembler, but from example the code area has name "AddIntsIn2sComp", and data area has name "intData", both looks to be arbitrary "human" names, just avoiding spaces. So as long as you write there something concatenated from 2-3 words, it should work (in worst case consult your compiler syntax manual).